# InsertItemTemplate From ListView Doesn't Appear

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates

When I create InsertItemTemplate in ListView control, it doesn't appear. Why ? Where is the problem here in this code ? I cannot see "Enter text" with TextBox control when I run it.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ChatListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceUserPosts" OnItemDataBound="ChatListView_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="postContent">
                <%# Eval("PostComment") %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="ENTER TEXT"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the InsertItemPosition like below:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChatListView.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to do that. So every time when I want to use InsertItemTemplate  I must set the location of InsertItemTemplate right ?

Comment: One more question to ask you. "ListViewItemType.InsertItem" method this return InsertItemTemplate or some kind of other item ?

Comment: Its a ListViewItem object.